# Compiler warning 'await' operator, should I ignore it?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, warnings, async-await

I have a little button code like this:

```
private void CreateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var MsgDialog = new MessageDialog("MY MESSAGE");
    MsgDialog.Commands.Add(new UICommand("OK", (UICommandInvokedHandler) =>
        {
            // IF USER PRESSES OK, CHECKBOX WILL GET CHECKED
            DontDisplayCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
        }));

       // DISPLAY MESSAGE IF TEXTBOX IS EMPTY
    if (TileName.Text == "")
        MsgDialog.ShowAsync();
    else
        // REST OF THE CODE;
}
```

The code works but it keeps giving me a warning:

> Because this call is not awaited, execution of the current method continues before the call is completed. Consider applying the 'await' operator to the result of the call.

Should/could I just ignore it? If not, how to I implement the 'await' operator in this case?

Comment: See this for the reason not to ignore the warning: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11147187/am-i-right-to-ignore-the-compiler-warning-for-lacking-await-for-this-async-call

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add `async` to the  method defintion

```
private async void CreateButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

and add `await` to

```
await MsgDialog.ShowAsync();
```